# Ubuntu 10.04 web browsers do not render some fonts

Tags: browser, ubuntu-10.04, fonts, rendering

I tried opening page which uses this font http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One however my web-browser whether it's chrome or firefox doesn't render it and just shows simple font (I thinks times new roman) however if I ssh from my machine to other machine which is also running linux and open same page with web browser inside it with X-server everything works fine.

Anyone knows why? How to fix it?

EDIT: html has this in `<head>` tag

```
<head> <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> </head>
```

Shouldn't my browser download that font automatically?

Comment: Have you checked in font manager that Poiret One is installed?

Comment: @BJ292 no, I don't know how to check and is it necessery for everyone to install that font if they visit that website which uses that font?

Comment: Unless it is using a WOFF file it needs to be available on the local PC. The font manager should be available under the graphics menu

Answer (score 0):

If Poiret One is not pre-installed on your PC, your browser can only render text using that font if the web page uses CSS3 to specify an accessible URL for a WOFF file that the browser can download.

It may be that the HTML and CSS don't provide this or that local network settings make the WOFF file inaccessible?

Comment: What if it's written like that? Shouldn't browser download it?
`<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>`